# 'Download a copy' option not visible in Sharepoint cloud

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I am newbie in using SharePoint cloud, currently working in Sharepoint cloud

project. I am trying to edit `Seattle.master` file, but there is no option found

in `Master Page gallery` to download the file. One of the [example](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/04/29/edit-existing-master-page-to-change-logo-hide-top-suite-links-etc-in-sharepoint-2013/) found

with Download option.

[image]

But it's not available in my SharePoint website.

[image]

Currently **SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure** and **SharePoint Server Publishing** activated in admin side (I have no Admin privilege, It's done by the Network administrator.), Is there any additional configuration needed from admin side to get "Download" option in context menu.

Could you please advice.

Comment: pls mark my answer if I have solved your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable this option at Library Level. to do this go to List Settings -> Advanced Settings -> under offline client availibility section, Select Yes -> Click OK.

Now you can see download option either by Right Click over the Document OR Under File tab in ribbon

[image]

Comment: If you don't see download option by directly doing Right click then try looking under "Advanced" you may willl download file option