# Unable to download PDF from Sharepoint

Tags: permissions, download, system-master-page

Can someone assist me, why can't I see option to download in sharepoint 2016?

cheers,
Emma.

Comment: Please provide more details/screen shot to understand better.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have the download permission - [this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/user-permissions-and-permission-levels) explains this in detail - compare the **View Only** permissions to the **Read** permission.  If you are in a View Only security group, you would not be able to download.

[image: Permissions screen shot View vs Read]

It's possible that the Sharepoint Admin has restricted access to the place this file is saved to make it 'read only' but not downloadable.  Check with SP Admin.  Then ask them to check one of your colleagues who is in the same user group (security group) you are in, for the sake of comparison.

If it is nothing to do with the download permissions, [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218921/remove-download-option-for-document-library) suggests some alternative reasons, for instance there Document Library that hosts the pdf file might be configured to restrict download - as user DvG says in his answer: `You can set "Download to Offline clients" as No at your library level settings. Go to Library Settings --> Advanced settings --> select NO To download`

I hope this helps